# How to make paddles move in pygame pong?

Tags: python, pygame

I am a beginner of pygame. Recently I code a `Pong` game.

However, I cannot make paddles move when I press the certain keys in keyboard. Can someone helps me check the code. I think maybe I have some problems in giving paddles' new position. But I cannot fix it. And hopefully give me some hints about that.

Thanks!

Code below:

```
import pygame, sys, time,math
from pygame.locals import *


# User-defined functions

def main():

   # Initialize pygame
   pygame.init()

   # Set window size and title, and frame delay
   surfaceSize = (500, 400) # window size
   windowTitle = 'Pong' #window title
   frameDelay = 0.005 # smaller is faster game

   # Create the window
   pygame.key.set_repeat(20, 20)
   surface = pygame.display.set_mode(surfaceSize, 0, 0)
   pygame.display.set_caption(windowTitle)

   # create and initialize red dot and blue dot
   gameOver = False
   color1=pygame.Color('white')
   center1 = [250, 200]
   radius1=10
   score=[0, 0]
   speed1=[4,1]
   location1=[50, 150]
   location2=[450, 150]
   size=(5, 100)
   position1=(0,0)
   position2=(350,0)

   rect1=pygame.Rect(location1,size)
   rect2=pygame.Rect(location2,size)

   # Draw objects
   pygame.draw.circle(surface, color1, center1, radius1, 0)

   # Refresh the display
   pygame.display.update()

   # Loop forever
   while True:
      # Handle events
      for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

   # Handle additional events

         if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_q:
               location1[1] =+ 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_p:
               location2[1] =+ 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
               location1[1] =- 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_i:
               location2[1] =- 1           

         if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_q:
               location1[1] =+ 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_p:
               location2[1] =+ 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
               location1[1] =- 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_i:
               location2[1] =- 0       

         # Handle additional events

      # Update and draw objects for the next frame
      gameOver = update(surface,color1,center1,radius1,speed1,rect1,rect2,score,position1,position2)


      # Refresh the display
      pygame.display.update()

      # Set the frame speed by pausing between frames
      time.sleep(frameDelay)

def update(surface,color1,center1,radius1,speed1,rect1,rect2,score,position1,position2):
   # Check if the game is over. If so, end the game and
   # returnTrue. Otherwise, erase the window, move the dots and
   # draw the dots return False.
   # - surface is the pygame.Surface object for the window
   eraseColor=pygame.Color('Black')
   surface.fill(eraseColor)
   moveDot(surface,center1,radius1,speed1,score,position1,position2)
   pygame.draw.circle(surface,color1,center1,radius1,0)
   r1=pygame.draw.rect(surface, color1, rect1)
   r2=pygame.draw.rect(surface, color1, rect2)
   if r1.collidepoint(center1) and speed1[0]<0:
      speed1[0]=-speed1[0]
   if r2.collidepoint(center1) and speed1[0]>0:
      speed1[0]=-speed1[0]




def moveDot(surface,center,radius,speed,score,position1,position2):
   #Moves the ball by changing the center of the ball by its speed
   #If dots hits left edge, top edge, right edge or bottom edge
   #of the window, the then the ball bounces
   size=surface.get_size()

   for coord in range(0,2):
      center[coord]=center[coord]+speed[coord]
      if center[coord]<radius:
         speed[coord]=-speed[coord]
      if center[coord]+radius>size[coord]:
         speed[coord]=-speed[coord]
   if center[0]<radius:
      score[0]=score[0]+1
   drawScore(center,surface,score,position2,0)
   if center[0]+radius>size[0]:
      score[1]=score[1]+1
   drawScore(center,surface,score,position1,1)


def drawScore(center1,surface,score,position,whichscore):
   FontSize=30
   FontColor=pygame.Color('White')
   String='Score : '
   font=pygame.font.SysFont(None, FontSize, True)
   surface1=font.render(String+str(score[whichscore]), True, FontColor,0)
   surface.blit(surface1,position)



main()
```

Comment: `location1[1] =- 0` What is this supposed to do? Did you mean to assign negative zero or did you mean to subtract zero? Either way, this is a silly thing to do. However, it is assigning negative 0 to location on every KEYUP, so your location will always be 0. Likewise `location1[1] =+ 1` is always assigning positive 1. I think you mean to increment location[1], and the syntax would be `location1[1] += 1`. I'd start there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You always use the rects `rect1` and `rect2` to draw your paddles. But to update their position, you try to change values in the lists `location1` and `location2`.

Stop it. Just alter the rects. The easiest way is to use [`move_ip`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.move_ip) to change the rects in place.

Also, if you want to keep your paddles moving while the players keep the movement keys pressed, use [`pygame.key.get_pressed`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) to get a list of all pressed keys (since pressing a key only generates a single `KEYDOWN` event, unless you mess with `pygame.key.set_repeat`, which you shouldn't).

So your code should look like this:

```
...
while True:
    # Handle events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
       if event.type == QUIT:
          pygame.quit()
          sys.exit()

    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if pressed[pygame.K_q]: rect1.move_ip(0, -1)
    if pressed[pygame.K_a]: rect1.move_ip(0,  1)
    if pressed[pygame.K_p]: rect2.move_ip(0, -1)
    if pressed[pygame.K_i]: rect2.move_ip(0,  1)

    gameOver = ...
    ...
```

Comment: This worked for me too. I tried to put the key event like ```if event.key == pygame.K_s: paddle1.move('bottom', 0.3)``` and it didn't work but after I did it this way it worked. Why didn't it work before? And I put the code directly in the ```while``` loop like in the code you've written.